# How to use Selenium WebDriver in a Jenkins job?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I have some JUnit tests written that use Selenium and the WebDriver of Chrome version 76.0.3809.68. Everything works fine when I execute the maven module with mvn clean install, but when I try to run it in a Jenkins job I get the following error:

```
The driver is not executable: /jenkins/workspace/webUI.ITests/target/test-classes/calculator/chromedriverunix
```

Now I already tried doing the same with a chromedriver.exe file, but I get the same error. Both of the drivers are from the selenium website and should be the correct ones. This is the code with which I am setting the drivers:

```
if (System.getenv("ON_JENKINS") == null) {
            URL res = this.getClass().getResource("chromedriverunix");
            File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            URL res = this.getClass().getResource("chromedriver.exe");
            File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

Both of the files are certainly present in the build. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to permissions on Unix. You can change it by executing `chmod 777 chromedriverunix` or `chmod +x chromedriverunix` in the folder where chromedriver is located.

Comment: Thank you I will try this solution in a couple of hours and I will tell you if it worked.

Comment: Ok so I tried your solution, but the problem is that when this job gets executed the first thing it does is that it fetches the head of a git repository and creates all of the files. So every time I execute the job the file is different than the one I have executed chmod 777 on. How can I surpass that problem?

Comment: @HristianIliev: Try making sure the file permissions of ChromeDriver.exe in your Git repository have execute permissions. You might need to remove the file from Git, then add it again after running `chmod` on it.